# IIS 8 error on windows server 2012 insufficient permission

Tags: credentials, iis-8

> There was an error when trying to connect. Do you want to retype your credentials and try again?
>
> Details:
>
> Filename: \?\C:Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
> Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Screenshot:

[image]

Suddenly I have this error when trying to access my application on IIS 8! Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you an administrator user?

Comment: Hi, I'm also hit by this. Did you ever find the fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this article helped me resolve the issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prashant_upadhyay/2011/09/20/unable-to-expand-server-node-in-the-iis-7-ui-with-shared-configuration/

The issue in my case was the account associated with configurationRedirection was locked, once enabled the issue was resolved.

I guess a similar issue would arise if the account did not have access to the Shared configuration folder, or if the account's password/credentials had changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error message for one of my users following a permissions change to his user account.   Turned out he had an old "disconnected" RDP session on the server. Once that was signed off (via task manager) the error went away.